# JQuery click text in span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to use JQuery to have a method fire when the following code gets clicked:

```
<div class="content_sub_list">
    <img src="/imgs/close-icon.jpg" class="exit_sub_list"/>
    hello
</div>
```

It is not doing anything and my JQuery code looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(
function() 
{ 
    $('#my_accnt').click(
    function() 
    {
      $('.content_sub_list').css("display", "block");
      $('.content_sub_list').css("margin-left", "4px");
      $('.content_sub_list').html('<div class="sub_list_header">My A<img src="/imgs/close-icon.jpg" class="exit_sub_list"/></div><BR />text');
    });
    $('#my_queue').click(
    function() 
    {
      $('.content_sub_list').css("display", "block");
      $('.content_sub_list').css("margin-left", "165px");
      $('.content_sub_list').html('<div class="sub_list_header">My Q<img src="/imgs/close-icon.jpg" class="exit_sub_list"/></div><BR />text');
    });
    $('.exit_sub_list').click(
    function() 
    {
        alert("hi");
      $('.content_sub_list').css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

My header looks like this:

```
    <script src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/mContentBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Other functions work in it except this one? for some reason.
So what am I doing wrong, or how i can get this to work? Thanks

Comment: works fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/HX7Kz/

Comment: Its working bro [test here](http://jsbin.com/alaji3)

Comment: Have you put the code in the `document.ready` handler?

Comment: are you attaching it to the document? because if you are you might be going to the wrong directory or have a typing error. Just had a problem with this last night (spent 2 hours on a bug that ended up I was attaching a js file with a type of `text/javasript`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working for me. Make sure you have jQuery loaded properly. You can either place jquery.js after your html or wrap your jquery code with a document.ready function.

like

```
(function() {
    $('.exit_sub_list').click(

    function() {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/p6Q2d/